# Magento2: During reindex Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock

Tags: magento2, reindex, deadlock, serialize, failure

During php `bin/magento indexer:reindex`

```
   SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_category_product_index` (`category_id`, `product_id`, `position`, `is_parent`, `store_id`, `visibility`) SELECT `cc`.`entity_id` AS `category_id`, `ccp`.`product_id`, ccp.position + 10000 AS `position`, 0 AS `is_parent`, 18 AS `store_id`, IFNULL(cpvs.value, cpvd.value) AS `visibility` FROM `catalog_category_entity` AS `cc`
     INNER JOIN `temp_catalog_category_tree_index_2843287b` AS `cc2` ON cc2.parent_id = cc.entity_id AND cc.entity_id NOT IN (1)
     INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `ccp` ON ccp.category_id = cc2.child_id
     INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `cpe` ON ccp.product_id = cpe.entity_id
     INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `cpw` ON cpw.product_id = ccp.product_id
     INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `cpsd` ON cpsd.entity_id = cpe.entity_id AND cpsd.store_id = 0 AND cpsd.attribute_id = 97
     LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `cpss` ON cpss.entity_id = cpe.entity_id AND cpss.attribute_id = cpsd.attribute_id AND cpss.store_id = 18
     INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `cpvd` ON cpvd.entity_id = cpe. entity_id AND cpvd.store_id = 0 AND cpvd.attribute_id = 99
     LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `cpvs` ON cpvs.entity_id = cpe.entity_id AND cpvs.attribute_id = cpvd.attribute_id AND cpvs.store_id = 18
     INNER JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `ccad` ON ccad.entity_id = cc.entity_id AND ccad.store_id = 0 AND ccad.attribute_id = 54
     LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `ccas` ON ccas.entity_id = cc.entity_id AND ccas.attribute_id = ccad.attribute_id AND ccas.store_id = 18 WHERE (cpw.website_id = '1') AND (IFNULL(cpss.value, cpsd.value) = 1) AND (IFNULL(cpvs.value, cpvd.value) IN (2, 3, 4)) AND (IFNULL(ccas.value, ccad.value) = 1) ORDER BY `cc`.`entity_id` ASC
     LIMIT 31500 OFFSET 500 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `category_id` = VALUES(`category_id`), `product_id` = VALUES(`product_id`), `position` = VALUES(`position`), `is_parent` = VALUES(`is_parent`), `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`), `visibility` = VALUES(`visibility`)
```

I try:

- reset all indexes
- also I try fix issue with deadlock:
  https://www.tigren.com/fix-deadlock-error-reindexing-magento-2/

Still the same issue. Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

sometimes help to edit `cron_schedule` table in DB to set all records to `valid`, to avoid automatic restart of indexer (you need to catch the moment when current job finish and there is `invalid` after `working` state)
than use fix from the link you mentioned and reindex (ideally from the command line)